# shopify node serve failed while installing the ngrok

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, ngrok

while invoking shopify node serve below issue occours using Shopify-CLI,

```
D:\User\Workspaces\Shopify\testapp1>shopify node serve
√ curl @ C:/Windows/System32/curl.EXE
√ tar @ C:/Windows/System32/tar.EXE

| Installing ngrok...

X System call failed: curl -o C:/Users/Logesh/AppData/Local/shopify/ngrok.zip https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip
```

Comment: Sometimes it happens while installing the Shopify CLI, you need to download the ngrok exe and place it into a suggested folder and then try again.

Comment: Yes Thanks Onkar, it helps. Not able to find the exact rootcause for this issue, but we can make this work by manually downloading ngrok and extract it and place into the shopify folder will work. For more info kindly visit:
https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/quot-shopify-node-serve-quot-command-problem/m-p/1355233#M73448